# How to make a button navigate between screens

Tags: authentication, button, swiftui, navigation, uinavigationbar

Can you make a navigable button to go to a different screen? I made a login screen and want the "login" button to be pressed and then take users to a different screen. I would also like for that screen to be a navigation bar for users to click through. Is this possible?

I'm new to swift ui and I'm creating an app for a class project. I've tried combining the login screen and the navigation bar in the content view, but no luck. Whenever I try to code a navigation with my "login" button, an error comes up. I'm a little lost and this is one thing I need to complete my app. I have watched numerous videos and read multiple articles, but still no answer and I'm confused. [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0bUD.png)

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context. Please add your code to the answer and the errors you are getting :)

Comment: import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoginScreen() }   }

Comment: The other part:                                                                                                      
TabView {
 ViewA()
 .badge(4)
 .tabItem() {
    Image(systemName: "message.fill")
    Text("Reading Groups"  }
     ViewB()
      .tabItem() {   Image(systemName: "book.fill")
    Text("My Books"}
    ViewC()
    .tabItem() { Image(systemName: "house.fill")
      Text("Home") }
  ViewD()
 .tabItem() {
Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
 Text("Search")   }
 ViewE()
 .tabItem() {
  Image(systemName: "person.fill")
 Text("Creator Profile")       }        }}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code (ideally, a [mre]) -- as you can see, code in comments does not format correctly.

Comment: import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoginScreen()  } }
        TabView {
          ViewA()              }
          ViewB()
              }
         ViewC()
               }
      ViewD()
                }
      ViewE()
              }
     }}

Comment: See [ask] about why to include code as text and not images